# wordpress: htaccess redirect url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to edit **Wordpress 3.5** .htaccess file to define some url redirect rules eg:

```
Redirect http://localhost/my_site/blog/cat/hello-world to http://localhost/my_site/cat/hello-world
```

I tried

```
Redirect 301 /localhost/my_site/blog/cat/hello-world/ http://localhost/my_site/hello-world/
```

and also

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_site/

Redirect 301 http://localhost/my_site/blog/cat/hello-world/ http://localhost/my_site/cat/hello-world/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /my_site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but browser says

> Page Not Found
>
> This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?

any idea.. how can i do this..?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `Redirect` in conjunction with mod_rewrite, just stick with mod_rewrite. Replace the `Redirect` with:

```
RewriteRule ^my_site/blog/cat/hello-world/ /my_site/cat/hello-world/ [L,R=301]
```